# How do I configure DNS in ubuntu? Why is it displayed that the domain name resolution has failed temporarily?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-20.04

I guess it's because my virtual machine is not connected to the Internet correctly, but I don't understand how to configure DNS?  I tried a lot, but I don’t quite understand it. It’s the first time to learn computer, hoping to help me, thank you

Answer (score -1):

The examples below use Cloudflare (1.1.1.1) and Google (8.8.8.8) DNS Servers. You might want to consider using a local DNS forwarder, or different, more privacy friendly public DNS servers, instead.

**If using Ubuntu Server:**

As per the documentation (https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-configuration), the resolver configuration file (/etc/resolv.conf), is dynamically generated by Netplan.

You can temporarily add nameserver entries to /etc/resolv.conf, for example:

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

However, those will be overwritten by Netplan. If the changes worked, make them permanent by looking for the Netplan configuration file, usually a .yaml in /etc/netplan. Add a nameserver block, or modify the existing one:

```
  nameservers:
      addresses: [1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8]
```

**If using Ubuntu Desktop:**

Assuming NetworkManager is installed:

Look for the connection name:

```
nmcli con
```

Add your DNS servers:

```
nmcli con mod <connectionName> ipv4.dns "1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8"
```

In the future, please consider using the https://askubuntu.com/ forums for these questions instead.